# Authorizing Drive and Sheets API on Android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-sheets

Okay so my Android app needs to access a users Google drive account and edit spreadsheets on that account. I'm using the Google Sheets API version 3.0 to edit the spreadsheets and Drive API Client Library for Java for drive access.
Now i know that the user needs to give permission for my app to access their information. Now please correct me but this is how i understand this is done.

1. Start activity for user to choose account
2. On the `onActivityResult` method check the result to see if user gave permission.

Now since i am using two API's(Drive and Spreadsheets) the user has to giver permission to both so the code i have below does the following.

1. Start activity for user to choose account
2. On the `onActivityResult` method get accountName choosen, and set that as the account that will be used.
3. In the `onActivityResult` method right after i set the accountName to be used, I make a call on a separate thread(Asyn Task) that will throw `UserRecoverableAuthIOException`, this exception is then used to prompt the user for permission for the Drive API.
4. In the `onActivityResult` method in response to the user granting permission i make another call on a seperate thread similiar to the last which will throw a `UserRecoverableAuthException` to authorize the Sheets API.

    Basically the user chooses the account they want to use and then the Drive API permission is granted and then Sheets API permission. **My Question: Is this how granting permission should be done? Is their a way to grant permission for both the Drive and Sheets API in one prompt?**

public class PlannerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
ListPlannerFragment mListFragment;
DetailPlannerFragment mDetailFragment;
YIGDataController mController;

private Drive mDrive;
private SpreadsheetService mSpreadsheetService;
private GoogleAccountCredential mGoogleAccountCredential;

private static final String TAG = "PlannerActivity";
protected static final int CHOOSE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
protected static final int AUTHORIZE_DRIVE_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
protected static final int AUTHORIZE_SHEETS_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE = 3;


//Life Cycle
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Google
    verifyGoogleAPIUse();

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onActivity result called: result code-" + resultCode + ", resultCode-" + resultCode);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case CHOOSE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST_CODE:

            Log.d(TAG,"Result of CHOOSE_ACCOUNT:");
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "CHOOSE_ACCOUNT successful:");
                String accountName = data.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                mGoogleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                mDrive = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),new GsonFactory(), mGoogleAccountCredential).setApplicationName("YIG Manager").build();
                AuthTryDrive authTryDrive = new AuthTryDrive();
                authTryDrive.execute();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "CHOOSE_ACCOUNT failure:");
                finish();
            }

            break;
        case AUTHORIZE_DRIVE_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE:

            Log.d(TAG,"Result of AUTHORIZE_DRIVE:");
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "AUTHORIZE_DRIVE_ACCESS success:");
                AuthTrySheets authTrySheets = new AuthTrySheets();
                authTrySheets.execute();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "AUTHORIZE_DRIVE_ACCESS failed, asking to choose new account:");
                finish();
            }

            break;
        case AUTHORIZE_SHEETS_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE:

            Log.d(TAG,"Result of AUTHORIZE_SHEETS:");
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "AUTHORIZE_SHEETS_ACCESS success:");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "AUTHORIZE_SHEETS_ACCESS failed, asking to choose new account:");
                finish();
            }

            break;
    }
}

//Util
private void verifyGoogleAPIUse(){
    mGoogleAccountCredential =GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
    Log.d(TAG,"Starting activity to choose account.");
    startActivityForResult(mGoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),CHOOSE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST_CODE);

}

private class AuthTryDrive extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Drive

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "In try statement of authorizing drive access");
            FileList f = mDrive.files().list().execute();
            f.toString();
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Drive user recoverable error");
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(),AUTHORIZE_DRIVE_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"io excpetion in drive");
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private class AuthTrySheets extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //SpreadSheets
        try {
            Log.d(TAG,"In try statement of authorizing sheets access");
            mSpreadsheetService = new SpreadsheetService("YIG Manager");
            mSpreadsheetService.setAuthSubToken(GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(PlannerActivity.this, mGoogleAccountCredential.getSelectedAccountName(), "oauth2:https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds"));
            URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
                    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

            SpreadsheetFeed spreadsheetFeed = mSpreadsheetService.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,SpreadsheetFeed.class);
            List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheetEntries = spreadsheetFeed.getEntries();
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Sheets user recoverable error");
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(),AUTHORIZE_SHEETS_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"GoogleAuthException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"IOException");
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"ServiceException" + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [GoogleAuthUtil.getToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) you can provide a space separated list of all of the scopes you want to authorize.  Just include both the drive and sheets scopes.  Some other places may technically still be able to throw an auth exception, but if you do that first, it shouldn't cause a prompt.

Comment: Could you show some code how you would do this and how one would transfer the auth token from drive over to sheets. I'm assuming you'd call something like mSpreadsheetService.setAuthToken(token)?

Comment: You don't need to transfer the oauth token.  The user only needs to authorize your app once per scope.  When they've done that, then you can request new oauth tokens without reprompting the user.  Thus, just call that getToken function up front to trigger the prompt, then do the same as what you are doing to get tokens as needed.

Comment: Okay so correct me if im wrong. The user only has to give permission once(the first time) at which point the Google servers will remember that my app, ass registered in the Google Developer console with SHA1 certificate and package name, was given permission and for future token requests will not require permission. Edit: i tried what you said and simply joined the scopes together in the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(), this caused the user prompt to give permission for the Drive and Sheets scope all together. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  There are some scenarios where permission would get rerequested, e.g. if the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app, but in general they should only be prompted once.